# is Revmob ,Admob ,apple id all behavioural advertising

Tags: ios

can we use Revmob ads such as fullScreen, banner ad in Kids game (5 and under,6-8,etc).
will it be against Apple’s iOS 7 App Store Kids category policy

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's Advertisement Policy

Comment: AFAIK, it won't be a good decision to include ads in Kids category Apps.

Comment: * 24.3: Apps in the Kids Category must get parental permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out of the app or engage in commerce
Specifically, your app includes advertisements that, when tapped, take the user to a web page. To be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines, all links out of the app must be behind a parental gate, and the parental gate may not be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a legal question about the Apple's Advertisement Policy. Questions about licensing should be asked on Programmers ;) -> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/